# Why am I getting this linker failure building my Unity project in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

[image]

This image is of my code when I am trying to compile my game in xcode. I have been
working on it for weeks and this is stopping me I have been trying to figure it out for days. Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Comment: Could you try copy-pasting the error code into a readable format? Note that providing an *image* of a *text-based* error code is often not received well. I would do it myself, if not for the immense length.

Comment: it would also help to provide background on what research you have done into this. For example, the error code clearly states that you are missing library files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Delete any x code instances of this project, and then re-export with unity(making sure your package name/and icon images are in there) after that open in x code and should work right away. I'm not sure why this is, probably happened from multiple instances of the same object with a few different library files with the same name not linking in the right order or something. Thanks for the responses though!